# Connect MacBook Pro Retina to VGA data projector

Tags: macbook-pro, projector, vga

What's the best adapter to connect a MBP Retina to a VGA data Projector?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Our community is dedicated to providing quality answers to great questions--see our [FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). As asked, your question really can't be answered and will only result in a laundry list of options based on individual opinions. To help improve the quality of the answers, please improve the question. What are ***your*** criteria? What constitutes "best" in your mind? What features are you looking for that Apple's solution doesn't provide?

Comment: Expanding on my initial objection to your question, what answer were you looking for that wasn't already available on the site? (See the possible duplicate question, and other suggestions in the sidebar. ) Duplicates aren't automatically disallowed but we do look for them to bring something new to the conversation. See [FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates).  Please don't be discouraged by my comments. We realize that Ask Different is *different* from other online forums. We welcome new members. I hope you'll stick around and help create the definitive source for Apple Q&A.

Answer (score 3):

Apple miniDisplayPort to VGA adapter

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Our community is dedicated to providing quality answers and we try to avoid single line responses. (That being said, I recognize that this was in response to a less than perfect question).  Could you please expand on your answer? What makes this the ***best*** option?

Comment: Actually there is not much to say about that answer, other than that apples adapter is he most reliable solution. I've tried a couple of third-party adapters and only one managed to work properly.

Comment: That very statement provides context and improves the quality of the answer. Adding that information would be a great edit. Again, I recognize this isn't a great question--see my comments above. Best Rgds!